# Trouble installing Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows (error with vcredist?)

Tags: runtime, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

**update: the same issue is happening with the visual c++ redistributables**

I'm having trouble installing Visual Studio 2013 for Windows (the version for developing apps). I'm trying to install this on the Surface Pro 2 256GB edition running an up to date windows 8.1.

I'm getting an error with the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.21005"

"The Temp folder is on a drive that is full or inaccessible. Free up space on the drive or verify that you have write permission on the Temp folder."

A screenshot of the issue:
[image]

I tried searching google but I wasn't able to find anyone else with the same problem (this error coming up on Visual Studio 2013). The suggestions I saw were to verify the hash of the iso to verify that it was correct, check that I have the proper write permissions to the temp folder, and to disable/enable user account control (UAC).

The sha1 of the iso I downloaded matched the hash listed on the download website. I also tried using the web installer and ran into the same issue.

The SYSTEM entry, my user account, and the ADMINISTRATORS entry all had full permissions on the %Temp% folder (which leads to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp).

User account control was enabled when I tried to install (it was on the second from the top entry, so from levels 0-3 it was on 2). I tried the install when this was disabled and when it was enabled (I also tried restarting between these changes).

Nothing so far has worked. I'd really appreciate some help in the issue. I'm pretty lost on where to go from here.

The log file throws its first and last errors here:

```
[0B94:0B50][2013-12-09T12:24:44]e000: Error 0x80070660: Failed to install MSI package.
[0B94:0B50][2013-12-09T12:24:44]e000: Error 0x80070660: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]e000: Error 0x80070660: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 534206  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 534206
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070660 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023264 (0x80070660), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, result: 0x80070660, restart: None
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]e000: Error 0x80070660: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0B94:0B50][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i318: Skipped rollback of package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i319: Applied rollback package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0B94:0B50][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i351: Removing cached package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{13A4EE12-23EA-3371-91EE-EFB36DDFFF3E}v12.0.21005\
[0B94:1388][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i304: Verified existing payload: cab45B5F4C0549AFC5572730914330147F5 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5411060C-8F8C-393D-8D3B-26AF2C92FABB}v12.0.21005\packages\vs_minshellcore\cab1.cab.
[1768:0AE0][2013-12-09T12:24:44]e000: Error 0x80070642: BA aborted verify of payload: cab45B5F4C0549AFC5572730914330147F5
[1768:0AE0][2013-12-09T12:24:44]e314: Failed to cache payload: cab45B5F4C0549AFC5572730914330147F5 from working path: C:\Users\Paarth\AppData\Local\Temp\{78095723-ced1-49b3-b0ac-8598452ef0ec}\cab45B5F4C0549AFC5572730914330147F5, error: 0x80070642.
[0B94:1388][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i351: Removing cached package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{13A4EE12-23EA-3371-91EE-EFB36DDFFF3E}v12.0.21005\
[0B94:1388][2013-12-09T12:24:44]w353: Unable to remove cached package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{13A4EE12-23EA-3371-91EE-EFB36DDFFF3E}v12.0.21005\, reason: 0x80070003. Continuing...
[0B94:1388][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i351: Removing cached package: Preparation_Uninstall, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\556D811C-F676-3675-83D7-C534B57A1C15\
[0B94:1388][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i351: Removing cached package: vs_preclean_winexpress, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\A2105C10829819F72E3A96DBFE7D9CA0972151F1\
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1527808  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 1159168
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 117164552192 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 117164552192 bytes
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[1768:176C][2013-12-09T12:24:44]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070660, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: have you moved the folder C:\Windows\Temp?

Comment: @magicandre1981 No, I haven't. One of the other recommendations I saw was to clear my local temp directory. Was I supposed to clear C:\Windows\Temp as well?

Comment: ask this Microsoft and provide them the log files: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup

Answer (score 4):

I came upon this question while looking to solve the same problem. I figured it out! Make sure your C:\Windows\Installer folder is accessible. I'm not sure why it's complaining about Temp, but there we go.

My C:\Windows\Installer folder wasn't a folder at all, but a shortcut to a location that no longer existed. Making it a folder fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case with Visual Studio 2017 installer, I got the same error message and I didn't even have any `C:\Windows\Installer`. I just created the folder and the installer works.